# CakePHP validation for file upload

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, file-upload

I'm trying to perform validation with cake 2.3.8 on a file upload to make sure that only PDF's can be uploaded. I'm loosly basing this off of [this](http://blog.the-nerd.be/2013/04/cakephp-file-upload-validation/) tutorial.

My form is displaying the asterisk next to the input, and when I remove the validation from my model the asterisk goes away. I'm assuming this means it "sees" the input for validation, but I just can't figure out why even the custom validation isn't being triggered.

Here's the form

```
echo $this->Form->create('Upload', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('file_upload', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('file_title');
echo $this->Form->end(__('Upload File!', true));
```

Here's the code in my Upload model

```
public function checkUpload(){
    echo "test";   //check to see if it reaches this...not displaying
    return false;  //the error message should be set just for testing, it's not displaying though
}


public $validate = array(
    'file_upload' => array(
        'extension' => array(
            'rule' => array('extension', array('pdf')),
             'message' => 'Only pdf files',
         ),
         'upload-file' => array(
                 'rule' => array('checkUpload'),
                 'message' => 'Error uploading file'
          )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer (albeit for `cakephp 1.3`):

In your `model` add the following `validation` to your `$validate` variable.

```
$this->validate = array(...

    // PDF File
    'pdf_file' => array(
        'extension' => array(
            'rule' => array('extension', array('pdf')),
            'message' => 'Only pdf files',
        ),
        'upload-file' => array(
            'rule' => array('uploadFile'), // Is a function below
            'message' => 'Error uploading file'
        )
    )

); // End $validate


/**
 * Used when validating a file upload in CakePHP
 *
 * @param Array $check Passed from $validate to this function containing our filename
 * @return boolean True or False is passed or failed validation
 */
public function uploadFile($check)
{
    // Shift the array to easily acces $_POST
    $uploadData = array_shift($check);

    // Basic checks
    if ($uploadData['size'] == 0 || $uploadData['error'] !== 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Upload folder and path
    $uploadFolder = 'files'. DS .'charitylogos';
    $fileName = time() . '.pdf';
    $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $fileName;

    // Make the dir if does not exist
    if(!file_exists($uploadFolder)){ mkdir($uploadFolder); }

    // Finally move from tmp to final location
    if (move_uploaded_file($uploadData['tmp_name'], $uploadPath))
    {
        $this->set('logo', $fileName);
        return true;
    }

    // Return false by default, should return true on success
    return false;
}
```

You may have to display the error validation messages yourself, you can do this using:

```
<!-- The classes are for twitter bootstrap 3 - replace with your own -->
<?= $form->error('pdf_file', null, array('class' => 'text-danger help-block'));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you try to debug sth in Cake, always use `debug(sth) // sth could be variable could be string could be anything, cuz in Cake debug means`

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(sth);
echo "</pre>";`
```

it's already formatted very well.
then after that **you have to  put** `die()` otherwise after echo sth it will load the view that's why you can't see it even there was an output.

Comment: what is sth? I tried exactly that and it says "Use of undefined constant sth - assumed 'sth' "

Comment: lol...sth means the thing you wanna debug....in this case you can do debug("here");

Comment: you got this error means you've entered the function checkUpload

Comment: I got it to work by manually setting the data and calling validates. I don't know why it wasn't calling before, especially since the asterisk lead me to believe it was.